# How to do a loop inside a loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, wp-reset-query

I'm trying to get posts from a custom posts using WP_Query.

```
<ul>
    <?php $query1 = query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('specialties') ));
        if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
        <!-- title from post type specialties -->
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php  
        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</ul>
```

It's working just fine. Now I need to get posts from another custom post and show inside the already created loop. Now the code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php $query1 = query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('specialties') ));
        if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
        <!-- title from post type specialties -->
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <ul>
            <?php query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('team') ));
                if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();
            ?>
            <!-- title from post type team -->
            <li><a href="" class=""><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
            <?php  
                endwhile; endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php  
        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a loop (inside another loop) to show posts from another custom post, but its not working. I also tried to add `wp_reset_query()` after the new `endif;` but it didn't work neither.

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure out what the problem is. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: you might need to reset the query before the second query and after it like you did there.

Comment: This question (and its answer) might help out: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71724/loop-within-a-loop

Answer (score -1):

What if you save each query in a variable ?

```
<ul>
    <?php $query1 = query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('specialties') ));
        if($query1->have_posts()): while($query1->have_posts()): $query1->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
        <!-- title from post type specialties -->
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <ul>
            <?php $query2 = query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => array('team') ));
                if($query2->have_posts()): while($query2->have_posts()): $query2->the_post();
            ?>
            <!-- title from post type team -->
            <li><a href="" class=""><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
            <?php  
                endwhile; endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php  
        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this a comment on the question or an actual answer? If it is an answer, please file an [edit] and explain _why_ that would help. [Please also read why one shouldn't use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385).