# The loop seems stuck to a single (now deleted) post

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, archives, advanced-custom-fields

At first I thought it was an ACF problem, but printing some values helped me to find out that somehow my Loop seems stuck on a single post, but only when some fields are concerned.

To sum up my setup: I have installed the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and defined some custom fields (mostly numerical ones), on which I built custom post types.

The first occurence of the problem apperead while I was developing an archive page for a custom post type: I got everything working but a few fields returned *always* the same values, those related to a specific post (post number 50). After some attempts to fix the code (which led to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216336/acf-get-field-return-fields-of-wrong-post)) I left the archive page behind and started working on the single page. Then, again, most of the fields worked fine, but a few (the *same* few of the archive page) kept returning always the same values (again, the values from post number 50). So I started printing out the post ID, and every time I call `get_the_ID()` I always get 50, even after I deleted said post, in a pretty useless attempt to get rid of its values.

I think it's a bit strange, but from the behaviour I'd say that the loop is somehow stuck on the same post, no matter where I call it.

Comment: what exactly wants to do?

Comment: I want to print out my custom fields (along with the rest of the post)

Comment: this is first post ID -50

Comment: Do you mean the default first post?

Comment: yes...id 50 is which post

Comment: I should've used wp_reset_postdata() at the end of the loop

Comment: Id 50 *was* a test post of one of the custom types. What is strange is that the post has been deleted but I still get id 50 (and now no data, of course)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35136/discussion-between-vasim-vanzara-and-frollo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! For any one in the future with the same problem:

ACF's `get_field_object()` apparently makes a WP_Query and doesn't clean up after so, since I called it for every post, I always got the same post after a certain point in the elaboration. I found the solution in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71724/loop-within-a-loop).

Some code for clarity:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
 <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
 //Some more prints
 <?php $field = get_field_object('my_field');
   $value = intval($field["value"]);
   $label = $field["choices"][$value];
   echo $label;
  //From this point on every custom field or other data came from the same post
 ?>
```

There are probably better ways to fix this, but it is simple and it works fine:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
 <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
 //Some more prints
 <?php 
   $backup = $post; //Backing up the current post
   $field = get_field_object('my_field');
   $value = intval($field["value"]);
   $label = $field["choices"][$value];
   echo $label;
   $post = $backup; //Restoring the post
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [wp_reset_query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) before the loop.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work