# How to set value in Query Loop?

Tags: posts, query

I have a Query:

```
<?php
                    $feature_big = array(
                        'posts_per_page'    => '1',
                        'meta_key' => $count_today,
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
                    );
                    $wp_feature_big = new WP_Query( $feature_big );
                ?>
                <?php if( $wp_feature_big->have_posts() ) : while( $wp_feature_big->have_posts() ) : $wp_feature_big->the_post(); ?>
                    /----------------------------here------------------/
                <?php endwhile; endif?>
```

Now, i want change value (posts_per_page, meta_key,...) in 'here'.
Is it possible? And How?
Thank you! Sorry my English :)

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can change it.

Comment: How? Thank you so much

Comment: What values do you want to set for those keys?

Comment: eg: `'posts_per_page'    => '1',` here you can change value 1 to 10 to show 10 posts per page

Comment: you will have to initiate new `WP_Query` object inside while loop with new args. then fetch all posts again inside that, need complete explanation ?

Comment: Thank all. But I need demo code.. :(

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not use `get_posts` ? Why try to reused a Query in a loop .... of that query

Comment: I want change value of 'meta_key', with 'if' in Query Loop...

Comment: try this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245734/90674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple nested [WP_Queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) as long as you [`reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/reset_postdata/) to get the outer loop back on track.

```
$query_args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'meta_key'       => $count_today,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
);

$outer_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );


while( $outer_query->have_posts() ) :

    // conditional if
    if( true ) {

        // change the query arg in the inner loop
        $query_args[ 'meta_key' ] = 'something_else';
    }

    // start an inner query with adjusted params
    $inner_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // nested loop
    while( $inner_query->have_posts() ) :

        // ...

    endwhile;

    // After looping through a nested query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in this query.
    $outer_query->reset_postdata();

endwhile;
```