# How to properly reset a nested WP_Query query

Tags: wp-query

I'm missing something here. What's the proper way to reset a query so that it doesn't interfere with any other queries it may be nested in?

**This is the kind of result I'm going for:**

> ### Main page
>
> This is the main page content. Now let's display some custom nested queries.
>
> **Outer page 1**
>
> ```
>  Inner post 1
>  Inner post 2
> ```
>
> *Outer page 1 content continued...*
>
> **Outer page 2**
>
> ```
>  Inner post 1
>  Inner post 2
> ```
>
> *Outer Page 2 content continued...*
>
> ...etc.

But I can't get the `Outer Page X content continued` part working—it always reverts to either the inner query or the main page query.

**Here's my page template.** It's commented with the behavior I get with each of the reset functions (`wp_reset_postdata()`, `wp_reset_query()`, `$query->reset_query()`, and `$query->reset_postdata()`).

```
// BEGIN PAGE TEMPLATE 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    the_title(); // "Main page"

    /* --------- OUTER QUERY --------- */
    $outer_query = new WP_Query( [ 'post_type' => 'page' ] );

    if ($outer_query->have_posts()) : 
        while ($outer_query->have_posts()) : $outer_query->the_post();
            the_title(); // "Outer page 1", "Outer page 2", etc.

                /* --------- INNER QUERY --------- */
                $inner_query = new WP_Query( [ 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 2 ] ); 

                if ($inner_query->have_posts()) :
                    while ($inner_query->have_posts()) : $inner_query->the_post();
                        the_title();
                    endwhile;
                endif;

            /**
             * Now I'm done with the inner query.
             * How do I get back to the outer query?
             * 
             * Desired value of the_title(): 
             *   "Outer page 1" on first iteration, "Outer page 2" on second, etc.
             */

            // wp_reset_postdata();            // Nope! Results in "Main page"
            // wp_reset_query();               // Nope! Results in "Main page" 
            // $inner_query->reset_postdata(); // Nope! Results in "Inner post 1"
            // $inner_query->reset_query();    // Nope! Results in "Inner post 2"
            // If no reset is used:            // Nope! Results in "Inner post 2"
            the_title();

        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Now back to the main page
    the_title(); // Works

endwhile;

// END OF PAGE TEMPLATE
```

What's the proper way to do this? I'm looking for a generalizable answer that doesn't rely on knowing how many levels deep the query is, or the context in which it's being used. i.e., something that could be extracted into a shortcode.

Comment: If you're trying to reset it to `$outer_query`, I think you want `$outer_query->reset_postdata();`, that's the query object that holds the `$post` data that you want.

Comment: If the ultimate goal of this is to be able to create a shortcode that doesn't pollute `$post`, then use `get_posts`, a `foreach` loop, and template tags that can be passed a post ID, and eliminate the need to worry about this entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This touches upon an answer provided here [Loop within a loop?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71724/loop-within-a-loop) except I posted the full code:

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()) :

    // initialization for $inner_args & backup the current global $post
    global $post;
    $backup = $post; 
    $inner_query = new WP_Query($inner_args);

    while ($inner_query->have_posts()) :
        // do something
    endwhile;
    $inner_query->reset_postdata();
    // restore the global $post from the previously created backup
    $post = $backup;

endwhile;
$query->reset_postdata();
```

The important thing here is you are setting the current post as a backup, because when the inner nested `WP_Query` postdata is set up, the prior loop's is lost.  After the inner query finishes looping, you can set the post back to your backup and continue in the "parent" loop.